# Testing Drawer Navigation Items with Robolectric 3.0+

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, robolectric

I am new on Android developement. I am developing my first project and want to make use of Robolectric for my Unit Tests.

Since I am a little lost, my question is quite straight: How can I test the right behavior when clicking on an item within a `Drawer Navigation`. I am mainly asking 
**how to simulate the click on an item**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "how to simulate the click on an item". What is the item? Are they buttons? Any class that extends `View` has `performClick()`, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()).

Comment: I am talking about a Drawer Navigation so an item is a ListView item.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Robolectric tests for Listview, [here?](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/77ae4054c6fd36bd2efa66068c63c7a4635a1593/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowListViewTest.java#L136)

Comment: What is the status of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize shadows such as the following:

```
ListView lvMenu = (ListView)mMainActivity.findViewById(R.id.lvMenu);
Shadows.shadowOf(lvMenu).performItemClick(0); //click first item 
Shadows.shadowOf(lvMenu).performItemClick(1); //click second item
```

Comment: Can you explain what is `R.id.lvMenu`? This code doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for logout MenuItem.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    TestActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(TestActivity.class);
}

@Test
public void onNavigationItemSelected(){
    // logout MenuItem
    activity.onNavigationItemSelected(new RoboMenuItem(R.id.logout));
    verify(presenter).logout();
}
```

TestActivity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.logout) {
            presenter.logout();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```